# Is it possible to simulate dynamic topologies in ns3

Tags: ns-3

I am trying to create simulation environment for some sort of routing protocol and in order to do this I need to simulate behaviors such as:

1. adding new nodes
2. adding new links
3. removing nodes and links

Is it possible to do this in ns-3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can do that, ns3 gives examples to bringing up and down node interfaces so you can observe the effect.

you can find this example in dynamic-global-routing.cc file